# Understand Twitter API

Tags: java, api, twitter

I'm working on a java problem that (at least is trying) to utilize the twitter API, however, it is my first project using any type of API and I am a little confused. What is the benefit of using a java library for the twitter API such as Twitter4J and how would one go about not using one? I'm a little fuzzy on the topic of APIs in general and I'm not finding anything in my searches that really makes it clear how to use one.Do I need to use a Java library or can I do it without one? what are the pros and cons of using one vs not using one. I am relatively new to this and am having some issues. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

First what an API is:

> An application programming interface (API) is a particular set of
>   rules ('code') and specifications that software programs can follow to
>   communicate with each other. It serves as an interface between
>   different software programs and facilitates their interaction, similar
>   to the way the user interface facilitates interaction between humans
>   and computers. An API can be created for applications, libraries,
>   operating systems, etc., as a way of defining their "vocabularies" and
>   resources request conventions (e.g. function-calling conventions). It
>   may include specifications for routines, data structures, object
>   classes, and protocols used to communicate between the consumer
>   program and the implementer program of the API

The use of the Twitter4J API would allow you to easily call commands that do complex operations, such as get tweets as they are coming in. For projects such as this, using an API is best way to go about it as you are also going to be required to get an access key which allows you permission to use the API.

**Examples using Twitter4J**: http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to distinguish between an "API" and a "Library"

- You NEED the Twitter API: it's the thing that connects twitter to your code. You can use this to send a "post this to my account" command for instance.
- You CAN use a library: it helps your code talk to the api, by doing some of the work for you. You can call a function with only a string as parameter, and this function calls the forementioned send-to-twitter API

You can ofcourse say things like that the library has an API, but this would be confusing the situation a bit.

In the end it is quite nice to use the library because it helps you by writing code in your language.